# How to save element attribute values as aliases in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, cypress

I am unable to save 2 href values for later validation in Cypress. Here's the code I am trying to test, there are 2 divs representing an entity with one anchor each, clicking one anchor will open a page with more details about the entity. Code simplified:

```
<div class="card-header">
  <a href="/entity/someDinamicId">
</div>
<div class="card-header">
  <a href="/entity/anotherDynamicId">
</div>
```

When opening one of the links, there will be `Next` and `Previous` links which will move to the next or previous entity. My scenario would be to check that these navigation links will load the correct URL. My intention was to save both href values to aliases and use it for validation, but this is not working (`cy.get('.card-header > a').invoke('attr', 'href').as('firstURL')`), when retrieving using alias I am getting an object, without the value in it.
My solution is to use closures, but it's really unreadable. Is there a better option? Cypress is great, but sometimes the async way makes it intricate for simple tasks.

```
    cy.get('.card-header > a').eq(1).invoke('attr', 'href').then((href) => {
        cy.get('.card-header > a').eq(0).then($el => {
            const firstCardURL = $el.attr('href')
            cy.wrap($el).click()
            cy.url().should('contain', '/entity/')
            cy.contains('Next')
                .click()
            cy.url().should('contain', href)
            cy.contains('Previous')
                .click()
            cy.url().should('contain', firstCardURL)
        })
    })
```

Comment: Could you provide your full code so it's easier to reproduce?

Comment: @konekoya Unfortunately no, it's a huge Angular app, not publicly accessible. Aliasing the components is not useful, they are not accessible anymore when running the validations